# Bitcoin Cross-compilation failed with errors in notification.cpp

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, compiling, bitcoin-qt-setup, open-source

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install build-essential libtool autotools-dev automake pkg-config bsdmainutils curl git
installed all the dependencies in dependencies.md
sudo apt install nsis
git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
cd bitcoin
sudo apt install g++-mingw-w64-x86-64-posix
PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's/:/mnt.*//g')
cd depends
make HOST=x86_64-w64-mingw32 -j9
cd ..
./autogen.sh
CONFIG_SITE=$PWD/depends/x86_64-w64-mingw32/share/config.site ./configure --prefix=/
make -j9
```

For Linux, the build was successful and the QT wallet is working correctly, but when I tried to build for Windows, the problem started with several errors in notificator.cpp, which is located in the qt folder.

Machine specifications

Debian bookworm LXQT Release: 12
AMD Ryzen 7 3800X
RAM 32GB
HDD 2TB
version of Bitcoin Core is latest[image]

Comment: Hi Nobody, this is a question and answer platform. What’s your question? If you want to file a bug, it might be better directed at the [Bitcoin Core repository](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin)

Comment: I already did this, but after a few minutes they closed the issue without giving any solution.

Comment: Assuming that you are talking about https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/29682, it looks like the people responding to your issue indicate that you are not following the instructions for cross-compiling for the version of Bitcoin Core you were trying to compile. What happens when you try to follow the documentation?

Comment: I actually built with posix and with win32 and got the same errors, but the build was successful for Linux, by the way, I build & cross compiled successfully other POW Kawpow, Progpowz, Heavyhash but for BTC I got these errors

Comment: If that was what you were trying to indicate with the last two comments in the thread, I think it would be easier to understand that if you edited your comments to elaborate a bit more. At least I didn’t understand from those comments what you seem to be telling me here now. I’m sure if you made clear that your issue persists even after following the advice of the documentation, that the issue would be reopened.

Comment: Your last answer gave me a little hope, I will of course do what you said, but then I should open a new issue or just to add comments to the closed issue?. I'm asking because almost all the time I solved these problems myself but now I'm looking for real help, anyway really appreciate your last answer

Comment: I think you should add another comment that clearly states the issue that you are running into and what you have tried. There are multiple contributors already engaging with the issue, if you add another comment they will see it and evaluate accordingly. As you can see from the repository having just shy of 30k issues and PRs, we get a lot of issues, and it is a common problem that people didn’t find the documentation or didn’t follow it. Since you have found an actual issue that persists given the documentation, you will stand apart by clearly stating that.

Comment: You really clarified things to me and what I should do. I'll do all what you said. Thank you so much